# How to print Categorical features in Machine Learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, data-science

assume I have a train dataset

r1: cheap, expensive -> price

r2: excited          -> entertainment

r3: hot, summer      -> weather

r4: money            -> price

r5: rain             -> weather

---

then I want to display it in this pattern:

price         -> cheap, expensive, money

entertainment -> excited

weather       -> hot, summer, rain

anyone knows? I'am doing a NLP research. thankyou.

Comment: Can you please add a few rows of your dataset as a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
# Dictionary of items
d = {'words' : [ [ 'cheap', 'expensive'], ['excited'], ['hot', 'summer'], ['money'], ['rain'] ], 
     'category': ['price', 'entertainment', 'weather', 'price', 'weather']}
# Convert dictionary to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
# Unpack the list of 'words' by joining with ','
df.words = df.words.str.join(',')
# Groupby and aggregate to get the unique 'words' for each 'category'
new_df = df.groupby('category').agg({'words':'unique'})
# Since the groupby results in a list of items, unpack by joining with ','
new_df.words = new_df.words.str.join(',')
# reset_index() to convert the groupby object to a dataframe
# This is optional. If not used, 'category' will the index of the dataframe.
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_df
```